# Forcing tall side panels to match height of middle content panel

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are many solutions to the problem of equal-height, fluid columns, but I haven't found much about forcing all columns to match the height of the shortest fluid-height column.  This might sound pointless, but I am trying to set up a page where a content panel defines the hight of its flanking navigation panels.  I have solved the problem with some trivial javascript (see below), but was hoping to do so elegantly with only html and css.

My javascript solution:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="panel textdiv side" id="layoutright">layoutright... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</div>
    <div class="panel textdiv side" id="layoutleft">layoutleft... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</div>  
    <div class="panel " id="layoutcenter">layoutcenter... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</div>
</body>

<style type="text/css">

body
{
    background-color:#DFDFDF;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.textDiv
{
    overflow: scroll;
}

.panel
{
    background-color: darkgray;
}

#layoutleft
{
    float:left;
    margin-left:3px;
}

#layoutcenter
{
    margin-left:106px;
    margin-right:106px;
}

#layoutright
{
    float:right;
    margin-right:3px;
}   

.side
{
    width:100px;
    height:1px;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    resizeWindowHandler = function()
    {
        var content = document.getElementById("layoutcenter");
        var contentHeight = content.offsetHeight;
        var left = document.getElementById("layoutleft");
        var right = document.getElementById("layoutright");
        left.style.height = contentHeight;
        right.style.height = contentHeight;
    }

    resizeWindowHandler();

    window.onresize = resizeWindowHandler;

</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to take another look at this just for fun.  Found a way that works regardless of whether the main element's hight is fixed or auto.

```
<style type="text/css">
        .panel
        {
            background-color: lightgray;
            position:relative;
        }

        #layoutleft
        {
            margin-left:-100px;
        }

        #layoutcenter
        {
            margin-left:100px;
            margin-right:100px;         
        }

        #layoutright
        {
            right:0px;
            margin-right:-100px;
        }   

        .side
        {
            width:100px;
            bottom:0px;
            top:0px;
            position:absolute;
            overflow-x:hidden;
            background-color:lightblue;
        }
</style>
```

---

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="panel " id="layoutcenter">
            <div class="panel textdiv side" id="layoutright">layoutright... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</div>
            <div class="panel textdiv side" id="layoutleft">layoutleft... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</div> 
            layoutcenter... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.


 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ncfmd/

HTML :

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="side1">
        Content content content content
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>MAIN CONTENT</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="side2">
        More content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.content {
    width: 700px;
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.side1, .side2 {position: absolute; width: 200px; top: 0;background: #666;height: 600px;border: 1px solid red;}
.side1 {left: 0;}
.side2 {right: 0;}

.main {
    margin: 0 0 0 225px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #999;
}
```

Basically, you hide the overflow of the main content, and set the sidebars to be absolutely positioned. Then give the middle column a margin to the left and fit it in the middle, and give it a height. The content will take it's height and hide the extra height of the sidebars. :)

Comment: This doesn't quite do it.  I played around with your code and couldn't get the side panels to scroll nicely when their content overflowed.  I've edited my own code to make what I want simpler -- no irrelevant divs

Comment: Ah you wanted the side panels to be scrollable?

Comment: Yeah.  Check out the code I posted originally--I cleaned it up a lot